# NSIS Silent Install changing default options

Tags: nsis, silent-installer

I have a third party application I would like to silent install from the command line.

The application is PPLive available at: http://www.pptv.com/en/

It is an NSIS installer, and currently when silently installed, installs toolbars, and additional pieces of software, launches on completion etc.

Without repackaging it, how do I control the checkbox options on the pages of the normal installer from the silent command line install.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control the components unless the installer has been coded specifically for it (By using a "answer" file/.ini or some parameter you pass on the commandline) NSIS itself only allows the author of the installer to know if it is in silent mode or not, the rest is up to them. You would have to ask the PPLive people about it (Or request that they add it if they don't support it already)

Comment: Do you have an example, maybe a URL, of a .nsi config file showing how to parse custom command line options?

Comment: @leif81: E.1.12 GetOptions in the helpfile

Answer (score 5):

NSIS supports the silent install option with the `/S` command line script, however, it only sets a flag that the install script can check:using [`IfSilent`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.4.12).

There is an example script [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/silent.nsi) that demonstrated a silent installation.

Comment: @Casey this option on command line is not working for me: i do `"C:\...makensis.exe" /S myFile.nsi` and option /S is not recognized. Where does it come from?